# await seems to quietly return

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have a method that calls await on an async method.

```
private async void LoadPic(string imageFileName)
{
    StorageFolder sf = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    StorageFolder subFolder = await sf.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
    StorageFile sfile = await subFolder.GetFileAsync(imageFileName);
```

When I set a break point on the very next line, the break point is never hit. It just drops out of the method and returns.

```
public PixelData GrabPixelData(string imageFileName)
{
    if (!ImageDictionary.ContainsKey(imageFileName))
    {
        // doesn't exist yet, so load it
        LoadPic(imageFileName);
    }

    PixelData pd = new PixelData();
    bool found = false;
    while( found == false ) {
        found = ImageDictionary.TryGetValue(imageFileName, out pd);
    }
    return pd;
   // throw new NullReferenceException();
}
```

After I call LoadPic() I added a loop that keeps checking to see if it added the image in this file to a Dictionary. It never seems to get added and just hangs.

This method worked fine on a child class that I abstracted it out of.

---

Edit:

Modified a couple things. Everything seems to work now, but when I assign the results to the child class I get a null exception error (even though the debugger doesn't indicate anything is null!).

I wonder if it has to do with the fact that it is wrapped in a Task.

Child class:

```
private async void LoadPic()
{
     // I realize the async void is to be avoided, but ... I'm not sure because there isn't anything I want it to return. Should it just return a dummy task?
     sat1.pixelData = await rootPage.GrabPixelData("sat1.png");
```

LoadPic:

```
        private async Task<PixelData> LoadPic(string imageFileName)
        {
            StorageFolder sf = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            StorageFolder subFolder = await sf.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
            StorageFile sfile = await subFolder.GetFileAsync(imageFileName);
...
            return pd;
```

GrabPixelData:

```
public async Task<PixelData> GrabPixelData(string imageFileName)
{
    if (!ImageDictionary.ContainsKey(imageFileName))
    {
        // doesn't exist yet, so load it
        PixelData pd = await LoadPic(imageFileName);
        ImageDictionary.Add(imageFileName, pd);
    }

    var test = ImageDictionary[imageFileName];

    return ImageDictionary[imageFileName];
}
```

Comment: As you never `await` on `LoadPic`, it will return there and continue execution under the assumption that you do not need to wait for it (therefore used as an asynchronous, fire and forget method call).  I would have expected it to eventually hit your breakpoint when those returned, but I have not actually used C# recently to verify.

Comment: @pickpg: Thanks for thinking it through with me. If I await on the LoadPic I have to declare the method async. Async methods have to return void or <T> and so there isn't a way to return my custom PixelData class. This worked in the child class without an await on the LoadPic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid `async void`. Also, polling shared state to detect completion of an asynchronous operation is a no-no. That kind of CPU usage can get your app rejected from the Windows Store.

I recommend you change `LoadPic` to return `Task<PixelData>`. Then change your `ImageDictionary` from `Dictionary<string, PixelData>` to `Dictionary<string, Task<PixelData>>`. Your `GrabPixelData` method can then look like this:

```
public Task<PixelData> GrabPixelData(string imageFileName)
{
  if (!ImageDictionary.ContainsKey(imageFileName))
  {
    // doesn't exist yet, so load it
    ImageDictionary.Add(imageFileName, LoadPic(imageFileName));
  }

  return ImageDictionary[imageFileName];
}
```

Comment: Ah! The learning curve on async is so high. Async infects everything it touches. You have to rearchitect everything! I had to call await on the call to LoadPic() above. That at least gets it compiling, but somehow a null exception hits when I try to assign the results of GrabPixelData (which is not null) to a PixelData object.

Comment: To respond to your edit, return `async Task` instead of `async void` and `await` the returned `Task`. Regarding the learning curve, you may find my [async/await intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Comment: @StephenCleary, your article are great, it finally did make my head suck up the idea of async and await. Thank you!